# google map : how to get location with markers

Tags: google-maps

I want to show google map on my application where i need to show the some placeholder/marker . but i'm only able to get the basic picture of location.

could you guys help me wht all parameter i need to pass in center tag or how i can exactly pass the position.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=gate way of india,IN&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Cla
```

i'm using .net application. it would be greate if you can give me some sample.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify marker location in lat-lng.

Try:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=gate%20way%20of%20india,IN&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false&markers=color:blue|label:A|18.92184,72.83470
```

More example at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example

Comment: thanks for reply. yes correct, but how i can get that 18.92184,72.83470 ( position)

Comment: use Geocoding service- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index#GeocodingResponses. You should be able to send HTTP requests and parse the JSON/XML response in your application.